# Running Python Script from Bash - How to Redirect the Python Logging File

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I am running a series of python scripts from a bash script.

eg

```sh
nohup python $IMPORTER_PATH/importer.py -t styles -e $ELASTIC_URL -j $STYLES_DATA_PATH  -b -f &>> "$LOG_PATH/styles-$(date "+%d-%b-%Y").log"
nohup python $IMPORTER_PATH/importer.py -t objects -e $ELASTIC_URL -j $OBJECTS_DATA_PATH  -b -f &>> "$LOG_PATH/objects-$(date "+%d-%b-%Y").log"
```

At the moment I am successfully generating log output of stdout and stderr with the use of `&>>`
My python script had been littered with useful print statements such as `print("Process started")` and therefore the bash generated log file did have some use.

However, I have recently been cleaning up my log files and using the python `logging` module to generate more focused log files.

Here's the extract from my `importer.py` script:

```py
import argparse
import logging

def parse_args(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--type", help="Type of data to import")

def main(argv):
    # Set up Logging levels
    logging.basicConfig(filename='importer.log',
                        filemode='w', level=logging.INFO)
    es_log = logging.getLogger("elasticsearch")
    es_log.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

    args = parse_args(argv)
    logging.info('Started with %s', args)
```

The problem now is that the `importer.log` is created wherever the bash script is run from, and because I have set `filemode='w'`, it gets overwritten as each python script is called.

Is there a way for me to redirect the output from importer.log to my dated log file such as `"$LOG_PATH/styles-$(date "+%d-%b-%Y").log"`?

Or should I add another argument to my importer.py ArgumentParser and pass it the destination path and file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the name of the log file as you want. Here is an example:

```
from datetime import datetime
log_name = f"importer_{datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d')}.log"
# This becomes: importer_2020-11-27.log
```

You can of course change the format of the date ecc...

You could also use this:

```
import os
script_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
# This points to your script: /path/to/script.py
```

To get the path of your script if you want to save the logs there.

```
log_name = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(script_path), log_name)
# now together with the first snippet of code you get: /path/to/importer_2020-11-27.log
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful, renaming the logs would ensure I had a different one for each process.